# Alerts only sending to users who have the default Full Control permissions

Tags: permissions

I am having an issue where I have some lists for managing employee leave requests.  How I have different levels of users using Full Control, Contribute for varying level administrators as well as a defined level for the employee.

I have found that only the person with Full Control is actually receiving their email alerts.  I have tested this with the users on Contribute and the custom permission and as soon as I give them full control, alerts work, if I put them back they don't.

From everything I have read on the contribute permission these users should be able to create alerts, so I don't understand why they aren't firing....  can someone help shed some light on this for me as I don't want all these users to have full control which would enable them to delete items.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mention "lists" - do all of your lists have the same permissions? Would need a bit more information about the lists and how they are interacting (lookup columns, item-level permissions, etc) to be able to pin-point the issue.

A common issue is that alerts do not work on lists that have the Advanced Settings > Item-level Permissions set to Read access and Create and Edit access based on who created the item.

[image: List settings for Item-level permissions]

So if a list has this set and another list uses it as a lookup field, I don't know how that would impact it.

If you cannot figure out this issue, a workaround would be to use a SharePoint Workflow to sends an email to the user (Created By, Modified By, other People-based field) based on a status level, item change, etc. If the lists are being used for managing leave requests, you could get a lot of functionality out of putting a workflow created in SharePoint Designer to use.